# PDE/ODE question, nonhomogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

So, this was a PDE question but my prof wanted me to solve it as an ODE, it's non homogeneous. So, the homogeneous eqn changed to an ODE would be $y''-yx^2=0$. I'm not sure what method to use to solve it. If it matters the RHS is $x \sin y$.

Comment: oops, it's supposed to be y"-yx^2=0

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. I have edited your post using TeX, please check if it is correct. The RHS here is 0, where does $x \sin y$ come in? What have your tried? Have you seen a similar problem before?

Comment: the original problem was a PDE. The eqn was, u_yy - ux^2 = xsin(y). We are asked to "obtain a general solution of the pde by regarding it as an ODE", so I changed it to y"-yx^2=0 (ODE). It's been a while since I did odes but don't we have to solve for RHS=0 first and then do something to get a particular solution, yp?

Comment: What is you rationale for changing the problem?

Comment: @HansEngler Because the question said "obtain a general solution of the pde by regarding it as an ODE"

Comment: So basically I had tried this but didn't think/know if it was right. Definitely won't be doing the thing w/ the bessel eqn bellow if there's another way to find a soln. I found characteristic EQN r^2-1=0, roots r=1, r=-1.Then was trying to find yp=Axsin(x) + Bxcos(x) +Dsin(x) + Ecos(x). I am not sure where the form for yp comes from, I was following the solution to a similar problem so was not sure if it applied here. Am I on the right track at all?

Answer (score 0):

Written our fully, the original problem is
$$
u_{yy}(x,y) - x^2u(x,y) = x \sin y \, 
$$
We may regard $x$ as a parameter. Then the general solution is if the form
$$
u(x,y) = A(x) u_1(x,y) + B(x) u_2(x,y) + u_3(x,y)
$$
where $u_{1,2}$ are any two linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous problem $u''(y) - x^2u(y) = 0$ and $u_3$ is a special solution of the inhomogeneous problem. Now clearly 
$$
u_1(x,y) = e^{xy}, \, u_2(x,y) = e^{-xy}
$$
are two solutions of the homogeneous problem and 
$u_3(x,y) = - \frac{x}{1+x^2} \sin y$
is a special solution. Therefore the general solution is
$$
u(x,y) = A(x)e^{xy} + B(x)e^{-xy} -  \frac{x}{1+x^2} \sin y
$$
where $A, B$ are arbitrary functions of $x$.

Comment: I don't understand how you obtain u3?

Comment: @Courtney -  I guessed a multiple of the right hand side and fiddled with the constant.